# Is there a way to make a field appear when you click a button in FlaskForm?

Tags: python, flask

I am in the process of designing a website for the Latin language. In the website, I have a feature called "Form Practice," where users can either enter a latin word OR choose a random verb, random adjective, random noun, random participle, or a random pronoun. You can see this layout of the feature in the image below:
 [Form Practice Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhtF.png)

As you can see from the image, there are many fields that the user can input. I store all of this information in a Flask Form in a python file, as shown below:

```
from flask import render_template, request, json, Response, redirect, flash, url_for, session
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, HiddenField, RadioField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class FormPracticeForm(FlaskForm):
form_name    = HiddenField('Form Name')
LatinWord    = StringField("Enter a word:",  validators=[DataRequired()], id="LatinWord", render_kw={'onkeypress': 'handle(event)'} )
Macrons      = RadioField(
                        u'Enter your choice:', 
                        choices=[
                            ('Yes', 'Yes'),
                            ('No', 'No')],
                        validators=[DataRequired()])

AdjectiveRandomButton   = SubmitField("Random Adjective")
NounRandomButton   = SubmitField("Random Noun")
VerbRandomButton   = SubmitField("Random Verb")
ParticipleRandomButton   = SubmitField("Random Participle")
PronounRandomButton   = SubmitField("Random Pronoun")

NextButton   = SubmitField("Next", render_kw={'autofocus': True})
```

Then, in the actual HTML file, I reference the flask form and also handle potential errors:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form name="login" action="" method="post" novalidate>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <h2> Form Practice </h2> <br>
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    This feature allows you to practice your word forms. 
                    Please enter a word or select a random word. In addition, please specify whether or not you want to use macrons to get started!
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    NOTE: If you haven't learned a particular form yet, feel free to leave it blank - it will not be counted towards your score.
                </div>    
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <b> Use Macrons: </b>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {% for subfield in form.Macrons %}
                            <div class="form-check">
                                {{ subfield }}
                                {{ subfield.label }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for error in form.Macrons.errors %}
                            <span class="error-message">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <b> Enter a Latin word: <br>   </b>
                {{ form.LatinWord(size=35) }}
                {% for error in form.LatinWord.errors %}
                    <span class="error-message"> {{ error }} </span>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <br>
                <b>OR click one of the buttons to generate a random word</b>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"> 
                    {{ form.VerbRandomButton() }}
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    {{ form.AdjectiveRandomButton() }} <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    {{ form.NounRandomButton() }} 
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    {{ form.ParticipleRandomButton() }} 
                </div>
                <div class="col"> 
                    {{ form.PronounRandomButton() }} 
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <br>
                {{ form.NextButton() }}
            </div>
            <script>
                function handle(e){
                    if(e.keyCode === 13){
                        e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that rusn
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        </fieldset>        
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I am not necessarily running into any problems right now, but I am stuck. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the "Random Noun" button, for example, a multi-select field catered to nouns appears below the button that the user can select. And then if the user wants to change their mind and wants to select a "Random Verb", the multi-select field that was there disappears and a new one appears under the "Random Verb" button and that is specialized to verbs. I am unsure how to do this using FlaskForms. I was considering switching AdjectiveRandomButton, NounRandomButton, VerbRandomButton, ParticipleRandomButton, and PronounRandomButton to a RadioField as a start, but am unsure where to go from there.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try using `if/else` conditions but that would be very hard to do it and it might get deeply nested as you project grows. I would suggest to switch from flask forms to JavaScript + jQuery. Basically what I do is I set up the front-end using [flask-wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#javascript-requests) so it would send a `SECRET_KEY` to validate the request in the back-end when submitting a form and sending it using `jQuery ajax call` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. Then using JavaScript you can quite easy manipulate data-flow and it's presentation / appearance as you have all the access to UI document elements.